# Create jquery functions in external files

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, external

I would like to create a js file with functions and call them in an other file like that :

utilities.myfunction();

How can I do this ?
It should seem like that :

utilities.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // unknow syntaxe ...
});
```

main.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var something = utilities.myfunction();
});
```

index.html :

```
<script  src="utilities.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you're trying, is to create a namespace (an object in the global scope) and attach your function to that, for example like this:

```
(function () {

    // Initialize namespace 'utilities' (or use existing one if present)
    window.utilities = window.utilities || {};

    // Add function 'myFunction' to the namespace
    utilities.myFunction = function () { ... };

})();
```

You can now use the function in a script later like this:

```
var something = utilities.myFunction();
```